# emacs xpath xml xslt

Tags: xml, xslt, xpath, emacs

I am using Emacs to develop some applications which work on XML documents, and I want to configure it to achieve the following goals:

1. When I am editing XML document, I want to have the possibility to invoke some function (e.g. `M-x get-xpath`) to get the xpath of element where cursor is currently placed.
2. When I am editing an XML document, I want to have the possibility to invoke some function (e.g. `M-x run-xslt-transformation /path/to/file/transform_01.xslt`) to run an XSLT transformation on current buffer

Can someone help me with configuring my emacs, please?

best regards,
Lukasz
http://www.wasthere.com ;)

Comment: Unrelated URL with smiley face makes your request look like spam.

Comment: By the way, the XPath language is quite different from the XML path of a node in your XML document, so I found the term XPath confusing here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest installing [nXML mode](http://www.thaiopensource.com/nxml-mode/).  It appears to support showing the current XML path as shown in http://www.emacswiki.org/cgi-bin/wiki/NxmlMode#toc11.

On your second question, you should be able to set up your favorite XSLT processor, then use something like the Emacs command "shell-command-to-string" to run it whenever you like.